How to config safeFactory.deploySafe?
On NeoX Testnet T4 I deployed the safe contracts v1.4.1 by myself, referring to https://www.zlog.in/post/deploy-safe-contracts/ (using entrance B) and https://github.com/Arachnid/deterministic-deployment-proxy :



Contract
Address




SingletonFactory
0x4e59b44847b379578588920ca78fbf26c0b4956c


GnosisSafeProxyFactory
0xa6B71E26C5e0845f74c812102Ca7114b6a896AB2


GnosisSafe
0xd9Db270c1B5E3Bd161E8c8503c55cEABeE709552


GnosisSafeL2
0x3E5c63644E683549055b9Be8653de26E0B4CD36E


DefaultCallbackHandler
0x1AC114C2099aFAf5261731655Dc6c306bFcd4Dbd


CompatibilityFallbackHandler
0xf48f2B2d2a534e402487b3ee7C18c33Aec0Fe5e4


MultiSend
0xA238CBeb142c10Ef7Ad8442C6D1f9E89e07e7761


MultiSendCallOnly
0x40A2aCCbd92BCA938b02010E17A5b8929b49130D


CreateCall
0x7cbB62EaA69F79e6873cD1ecB2392971036cFAa4


SignMessageLib
0xA65387F16B013cf2Af4605Ad8aA5ec25a2cbA3a2


SimulateTxAccessor
0x59AD6735bCd8152B84860Cb256dD9e96b85F69Da



Then I am trying to deploy a safe with @safe-global/protocol-kit. I have the following codes:
import { SafeAccountConfig, SafeFactory } from '@safe-global/protocol-kit'
import { SafeVersion } from '@safe-global/safe-core-sdk-types'

const config = {
    RPC_URL: "https://neoxt4seed1.ngd.network/",
    DEPLOYER_ADDRESS_PRIVATE_KEY: '...',  // (Could I use any private key with enough gas?)
    DEPLOY_SAFE: {
      OWNERS: ['0x9C126aa4Eb6D110D646139969774F2c5b64dD279', '0xeB7E951F2D1A38188762dF12E0703aE16F76Ab73', "0xfBf75C9EEE56432aD1F12D6d3816EB027610f675"],
      THRESHOLD: 2, // <SAFE_THRESHOLD>
      SALT_NONCE: '150000',
      SAFE_VERSION: "1.4.1"
    }
  }
  const chainId = 12227332;
  const contractNetworks= {
    [chainId]: {
      safeSingletonAddress: '0x4e59b44847b379578588920ca78fbf26c0b4956c',
      safeProxyFactoryAddress: '0xa6B71E26C5e0845f74c812102Ca7114b6a896AB2',
      multiSendAddress: '0xA238CBeb142c10Ef7Ad8442C6D1f9E89e07e7761',
      multiSendCallOnlyAddress: '0x40A2aCCbd92BCA938b02010E17A5b8929b49130D',
      fallbackHandlerAddress: '0xf48f2B2d2a534e402487b3ee7C18c33Aec0Fe5e4',
      signMessageLibAddress: '0xA65387F16B013cf2Af4605Ad8aA5ec25a2cbA3a2',
      createCallAddress: '0x7cbB62EaA69F79e6873cD1ecB2392971036cFAa4',
      simulateTxAccessorAddress: '0x59AD6735bCd8152B84860Cb256dD9e96b85F69Da',
    }
  }

async function main() {
    const safeVersion = config.DEPLOY_SAFE.SAFE_VERSION as SafeVersion
    const safeFactory = await SafeFactory.init({
        provider: config.RPC_URL,
        signer: config.DEPLOYER_ADDRESS_PRIVATE_KEY,
        safeVersion,
        isL1SafeSingleton: true,
        contractNetworks
      })
    console.log(await safeFactory.getAddress())
        // Config of the deployed Safe
  const safeAccountConfig: SafeAccountConfig = {
    owners: config.DEPLOY_SAFE.OWNERS,
    threshold: config.DEPLOY_SAFE.THRESHOLD
  }
  function callback(txHash: string) {
    console.log('Transaction hash:', txHash)
  }

  // Deploy Safe
  const safe = await safeFactory.deploySafe({
    safeAccountConfig,
    // saltNonce,
    callback
  })

  console.log('Deployed Safe:', await safe.getAddress())
}

main()

And I got the following errors:
Error: missing revert data (action="call", data=null, reason=null, transaction={ "data": "0xffa1ad74", "from": "0x9C126aa4Eb6D110D646139969774F2c5b64dD279", "to": "0x4e59b44847b379578588920cA78FbF26c0B4956C" }, invocation=null, revert=null, code=CALL_EXCEPTION, version=6.13.1)
    at makeError (safe-global/test_sdk/node_modules/ethers/lib.commonjs/utils/errors.js:129:21)
    at getBuiltinCallException (safe-global/test_sdk/node_modules/ethers/lib.commonjs/abi/abi-coder.js:105:37)
    at AbiCoder.getBuiltinCallException (safe-global/test_sdk/node_modules/ethers/lib.commonjs/abi/abi-coder.js:206:16)
    at JsonRpcProvider.getRpcError (safe-global/test_sdk/node_modules/ethers/lib.commonjs/providers/provider-jsonrpc.js:676:43)
    at safe-global/test_sdk/node_modules/ethers/lib.commonjs/providers/provider-jsonrpc.js:302:45
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  code: 'CALL_EXCEPTION',
  action: 'call',
  data: null,
  reason: null,
  transaction: {
    to: '0x4e59b44847b379578588920cA78FbF26c0B4956C',
    data: '0xffa1ad74',
    from: '0x9C126aa4Eb6D110D646139969774F2c5b64dD279'
  },
  invocation: null,
  revert: null,
  shortMessage: 'missing revert data',
  info: {
    error: { code: -32000, message: 'gas uint64 overflow' },
    payload: {
      method: 'eth_call',
      params: [
        {
          from: '0x9c126aa4eb6d110d646139969774f2c5b64dd279',
          to: '0x4e59b44847b379578588920ca78fbf26c0b4956c',
          data: '0xffa1ad74'
        },
        'latest'
      ],
      id: 9,
      jsonrpc: '2.0'
    }
  }
}

NeoX Testnet T4 info:
HTTPS RPC URL: https://neoxt4seed1.ngd.network/
WSS Endpoint:
wss://neoxt4wss1.ngd.network
Chain ID: 12227332
Currency: GAS
Explorer URL: https://xt4scan.ngd.network/

It seems safeSingletonAddress: '0xd9Db270c1B5E3Bd161E8c8503c55cEABeE709552' makes some progress

It seems that NeoX is not currently supported by Safe{Core} SDK. This explains why the SDK will not work properly, as it needs to send transaction data to Safe API infrastructure, which is not configured for this network.
You can follow this guide for making Safe support this new chain.
Hope it helps; Best, Louis

Many thanks. I am following the guide, but I cannot wait to have a test.
